# Could I use this Sanitary tee with left and right inlet?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, sink, vent

My toilet, sink, and tub are all tied in to a cast iron Wye, and my sink is not vented so I want to re arrange the plumbing. Would this setup be up to code using a left and right side inlets facing each other and the toilet draining in the middle. I read somewhere you could not have to waste lines facing each other. The main waste lines are 4 inches and the sink and tub would be 2 inches coming in to the San Tee fitting with the left and right inlets. [image: Plumbing setup]

Here is the link for the Sanitary tee I will be using.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/NIBCO-4-in-x-4-in-x-4-in-x-2-in-x-2-in-PVC-DWV-All-Hub-Sanitary-Tee-with-Right-and-Left-Inlets-C4870HD44422/203643580

Comment: What is the applicable plumbing code of your local authority having jurisdiction? (LAHJ)  - that weeds out all but one of the places to "read things somewhere" and gets to an actual answer faster... Also may matter how far from the toilet to this tee entry?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the distance of stuff to the vent/drain matters if you need a separate vent or an extra pipe to the vent stack.   From the diagram you might want/need to change the wye.

Comment: I am in MA they follow the UPC but it does not clarify on using a that specific tee that Home Depot sells. The tee is right behind the toilet. So it is 15 inches from the center of the toilet flange.

Comment: Is the toilet some kind of wall mount type?

Comment: No the toilet flange will be 12.5 off the finished wall.